# How to extract specific lines from a text file using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a text file that looks like this.

```
A   102
B   456
C   678
H    A       B        C      D       E        F      G       H       I       J
    1.18    0.20    0.23    0.05    1.89    0.72    0.11    0.49    0.31    1.45
    3.23    0.06    2.67    1.96    0.76    0.97    0.84    0.77    0.39    1.08
```

I need to extract all the lines that start with B,H and two  lines after H . How can I do this using awk?

The expected output would be

```
 B   456
 H    A       B        C      D       E        F      G       H       I       J
    1.18    0.20    0.23    0.05    1.89    0.72    0.11    0.49    0.31    1.45
    3.23    0.06    2.67    1.96    0.76    0.97    0.84    0.77    0.39    1.08
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: The last two lines in your output don't start with B or H and.  Your output also has blank lines.  Please specify your requirements more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the blank line after `B` in your output (your problem specifications give no indication as to why that blank line is in the output, so I'm assuming it should not be there):

```
awk '/^H/{t=3} /^B/ || t-- >0' input.file
```

will print all lines that start with `B` and each line that starts with `H` along with the next two lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^[BH]/ || /^[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]/' inputfile
```

Comment: This is nice, but only works if H and B are the only fields that may signal a begin-tabular-data. It does solve the requirement of the OP to his/her best specification though.

Comment: This will not print the last 2 lines with numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-3.00$ cat t
A   102
B   456
C   678
H    A       B        C      D       E        F      G       H       I       J
    1.18    0.20    0.23    0.05    1.89    0.72    0.11    0.49    0.31    1.45
    3.23    0.06    2.67    1.96    0.76    0.97    0.84    0.77    0.39    1.08

bash-3.00$ awk '{if(( $1 == "B") || ($1 == "H") || ($0 ~ /^ / )) print;}' t
B   456
H    A       B        C      D       E        F      G       H       I       J
    1.18    0.20    0.23    0.05    1.89    0.72    0.11    0.49    0.31    1.45
    3.23    0.06    2.67    1.96    0.76    0.97    0.84    0.77    0.39    1.08
```

OR in short

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /^[BH ]/ ) print;}' t
```

OR even shorter

```
awk '/^[BH ]/' t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat filename.txt | awk '/^[B(H(^ .*$){2})].*$/' > output.txt
```

**EDIT**: Updated for OP's edit

Answer (score 0):

If `H` and `B` aren't the only headers that are sent before tabular data and you intend to omit those blocks of data (you don't specify the requirements fully) you have to use a flip-flop to remember if you're currently in a block you want to keep or not:

```
awk '/^[^ 0-9]/ {inblock=0}; /^[BH]/ {inblock=1}; { if (inblock) print }' d.txt
```